# Identifying a vector space V with $\mathbb {C}^n $

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking at a proof. First for a unitary vector Space $(V,\langle\ ,\ \rangle)$ they defined the conjugate of an endomorphism $\phi:V \rightarrow V$ as the endomorphism $\phi^*:V \rightarrow V$ for which $\langle\phi(v),w\rangle=\langle v,\phi^*(w)\rangle~\forall v,w \in V$
holds.

Now the proposition is that if the unitary vector space $(V; \langle\ ,\ \rangle)$ is finite-dimensional then $\phi^*$ exists and $M_B(\phi)^*=M_B(\phi^*) $.

$*$ also serves for the conjugate transposed of a matrix (I think usually it's denoted with $H$), $ \phi:V \rightarrow V $ is an endomorphism and $M_B(\phi) $ is the matrix of $ \phi$ regarding an orthonormal basis $B$ of $V$. The proof itself is rather short.

They identify V with $ \mathbb{C}^n \ (n:=\dim(V))$ and then argue that $ \phi(x)=Ax$. Then it follows that$$\langle x,\phi(v)\rangle=x^*Av=(A^*x)^*v=\langle A^*x,v\rangle.$$

I think I can make sense of it for $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the standard scalar product since then we can define  $A:= M_E(\phi)$ where $E$ is the canonical basis and the argument in the proof then shows that $M_E(\phi)^*=M_E(\phi^*)$ and  $M_B(\phi)^*=M_B(\phi^*)$ follows because the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $E$ is orthogonal. However I'm not really sure how the first  very first part about identifying works. In the proof they use the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ alongside a property of it: $\langle x,v\rangle=x^*v$. However that isn't necessarily true for the scalar product of any given unitary vector space $(V; \langle\ ,\ \rangle)$, right? So my question boils down to how does it follow that if the proposition is true for $(\mathbb{C}^n; \langle\ ,\ \rangle)$ with the standard scalar product it is also true for any finite dimensional unitary vector space $(V; \langle\ ,\ \rangle)$?

Comment: here you need to report how the scalar product is defined in the first place. (because different books report different definitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard way to carry results from $\mathbb C^n$ with standard inner product to any inner product space $V$ of finite dimension.

For any *unitary vector space* $(V,\langle,\rangle_V)$ (a vector space with an inner product) with $\dim V=n<+\infty$ you can find a basis $v_1,...,v_n$ of $V$ such that $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle_V=\delta_{ij}$.

Define $L:V\to\mathbb C^n$ by sending $v_i$ to $e_i$ (the canonical basis of $\mathbb C^n$) and extending by linearity. $L$ is invertible and we have
$$
\langle v,w\rangle_V=\langle Lv,Lw\rangle_{\mathbb C^n},\qquad\forall v,w\in V\qquad (*).
$$
(Here we denote $\langle,\rangle_{\mathbb C^n}$ the standard scalar product on $\mathbb C^n$.)

Define
$$
A=L\circ\phi\circ L^{-1}.
$$
Now, $A:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$ is linear and you know the result, namely that there exists $A^*:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$ linear such that
$$
\langle Ae,f\rangle_{\mathbb C^n}=\langle e,A^*f\rangle_{\mathbb C^n}
$$
for all $e,f\in\mathbb C^n$. (As you correctly say, $A$ is multiplication by an $n\times n$ matrix $M_A$ and it suffices to take $A^*$ to be multiplication by the conjugate transpose matrix of $M_A$.)

We claim that $\phi^*:=L^{-1}\circ A^*\circ L:V\to V$ does the job. Indeed,
$$
\langle v,\phi^*w\rangle_V=\langle v,L^{-1}A^*Lw\rangle_V=
\langle Lv,A^*Lw\rangle_{\mathbb C^n}=
\langle ALv,Lw\rangle_{\mathbb C^n}=
\langle L^{-1}ALv,w\rangle_{V}
=\langle \phi v,w\rangle_{V}
$$
where we use $(*)$.

ADDITION TO ADDRESS THE COMMENT.
One fact which I glossed over is the following: the linear operator $\phi^*$ is defined by this argument **once a basis $v_1,...,v_n$ has been fixed**. It may seem in principle possible that this linear operator $\phi^*$ so defined depends on the choice of basis. However, this is not possible, because (for a fixed $\phi$) an operator $\phi^*:V\to V$ such that
$$
\langle v,\phi^* w\rangle_V=\langle \phi v, w\rangle_V
$$
is unique. Indeed, if we have two of them, say $\phi^*,\tilde\phi^*$, then
$$
\langle v,\phi^* w\rangle_V=\langle \phi v, w\rangle_V=\langle v,\tilde\phi^* w\rangle_V,\qquad \forall v,w\in V,
$$
so that, for all $v\in V$ we have
$$
\langle v,(\phi^*-\tilde\phi^*)w\rangle_V=0
$$
and by the properties of the inner product it follows that $\phi^*w=\tilde\phi^*w$, and this holds true for all $w\in V$, i.e., $\tilde\phi^*=\phi^*$.

At this point, it only remains to convince yourself that the matrix representing $\phi$ in the basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is precisely the matrix $M_A$ introduced in the argument above and that the matrix representing $\phi^*$ in the same basis is, by construction, the conjugate transpose of $M_A$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me in terms of how to carry over the existence of $\phi^*$ to V but I'm still a bit confused by how this carries the other part ( $M_B(\phi)^*=M_B(\phi^*)$ for an orthonormal basis B) over. I tried fitting L and A into the $M_B$ notation but I got a bit lost there.

Comment: Thanks, now your answer solved my question, I just got a bit confused with my $M_B$ notation.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem completely, do not forget to mark your question as closed by accepting an answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question :)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

Your post is slightly all over the place but I've gotten the gist of what you're trying to ask. So, you want a proof of the following result:

Let $(V,\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a unitary space which is finite-dimensional. Then, $\phi^{\star}$ exists and $M_B(\phi)^{\star} = M_B(\phi^{\star})$, where $B$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$.

I'm going to assume linearity in the first argument. Let's start with existence. I'll try to motivate the proof, rather than just give it. This will teach you how you could potentially come up with these arguments by yourself.

**Proof:**

Suppose that $\phi^{\star}$ does exist. Let's try to determine its matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis $B$ first. The columns of this matrix will be the coefficients of the expansion of $\phi^{\star}(v_j)$ in the basis $B$. So, let $B = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. Then:
$$\phi^{\star}(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \phi^{\star}(v_j),v_i \rangle v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{\langle v_i, \phi^{\star}(v_j) \rangle} v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{\langle \phi(v_i),v_j \rangle} v_i$$
On the other hand,we know that:
$$\phi(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle \phi(v_j),v_i \rangle v_i$$

But now, notice that we obtain the coefficients of $\phi^{\star}(v_j)$ be taking the conjugate transpose of the coefficients of $\phi(v_j)$ and that is what we wanted to show. So, it remains to be shown that $\phi^{\star}$ itself exists.

First of all, we should prove a uniqueness statement. Suppose that there are two linear maps $S,T: V \to V$ such that:
$$\forall v,w \in V: \langle \phi(v),w \rangle = \langle v,S(w) \langle = \langle v,T(w) \rangle$$
I claim that $S = T$. Indeed:
$$\forall v,w \in V: \langle v, (S-T)(w) \rangle = 0$$
For each $w$, select $v = (S-T)(w)$. This implies that $S(w) = T(w)$ so we are done. Now, what this shows is that if you have two maps with the property that you want, then they really are just the same map.

It remains to be shown that we can actually give an example of said map. Let $B = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis. Now, the map $\phi^{\star}$ is determined by its action on this basis. We define:
$$\phi^{\star}(v_j) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle v_j, \phi(v_i) \rangle v_i$$

Why did I define it this way? Well, if $\phi^{\star}(v_j)$ was well-defined, then I would write it as:
$$\phi^{\star}(v_j) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \phi^{\star}(v_j),v_i \rangle v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{\langle v_i, \phi^{\star}(v_j) \rangle} v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{\langle \phi(v_i), v_j \rangle} v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle v_j, \phi(v_i) \rangle v_i$$
where I've used the property that we are trying to prove. See, what I've done is that I've cheated a little bit by playing around with the property (all the while assuming that $\phi^{\star}$ exists and satisfies it) and then seeing if I can find a way to define $\phi^{\star}$ by using that property. Now, we just need to check that the required property does hold when we define $\phi^{\star}$ in this way.

It's useful to establish the following first:
$$\langle v_i, \phi^{\star}(v_j) \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \overline{\langle v_j,\phi(v_k) \rangle} \langle v_i,v_k \rangle = \overline{\langle v_j,\phi(v_i) \rangle} = \langle \phi(v_i),v_j \rangle$$

where I have used the fact that we are dealing with an orthonormal basis. Next, let $v,w \in V$. Then:
$$\langle v,\phi^{\star}(w) \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_i \overline{\beta_j} \langle v_i, \phi^{\star}(v_j) \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_i \overline{\beta_j} \langle \phi(v_i),v_j \rangle = \langle \phi(v),w \rangle$$
where I have used the fact that $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i v_i$ and $w = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \beta_j v_j$. So, we are done :)